# Xubuntu desktop settings not showing wallpapers

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, desktop-background

This is what I get when I open desktop settings on the "Background" tab. The directory I have browsed to has pictures in it but they are not shown when selecting a desktop background.

Someone please help, I've had enough of the vanilla Xubuntu wallpaper.

[image: screenshot showing the Desktop dialog window]

Comment: What type of 'pictures'.   The wallpapers that show in that dialog are restricted to types that can be used as backgrounds, some images (even if given a .jpg extension) cannot be used. If you examine your files (eg. `file whattype.jpg` you'll see what type of images they are, and can check to see if they're compatible)  You didn't give release details, so I can't provide more.

Comment: You see a folder button there. Just point that to a folder where you have wallpapers, or, alternatively, copy some wallpaper graphics into the folder revealed in that dialog. Normally, a few choices are available. Not sure what happened on your system to have no choices (i.e., no graphics files in that folder).

Comment: Its Ubuntu 18.04.3, installed from the mini.iso and I installed Xubuntu minimal when I selected from the software I wanted to install. All the images are compatible, the thumbnails just aren't showing, so I cannot chose an image I want. And I have browsed to the correct folder.

Answer (score 1):

If ~/.cache/thumbnails is write protected, unable to be created or otherwise missing, this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

After some disappointing attempts, this worked for me with Xubuntu 20.04: you got to chose "other" from "Folder:Wallpapers" in "Desktop Settings" (see you picture in your first post, then select the folder your picture is in, and choose the picture (jpg, png and bmp all worked for me).

Comment: I can't choose any picture (jpg/png), they're all disabled (grey).